# Gamma CDF in Python

Tags: python, gamma-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, scipy

I'm working through the [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bayesian-statistics/home/welcome) course *Bayesian Statistics: From Concept to Data Analysis* by the University of California, Santa Cruz and there is a [worksheet](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_62835c1b5b81af286ba54a920f2a4d5f_L5_background.pdf?Expires=1496966400&Signature=DScYfT6c6igocGYaEgsbwPJUcSGzR-EfxKcOaimLMLKgPuVMHhcOcp831GSM7A7PEQO03WHmmdrReIUlot5blGG5N4Zy6lYx5qgq9ifQE229jAsUr7zk78hs91SHiT6DyRsGnJuENrMA5C05FPxdKFzF4Gv2XkTU47q4Tt~WSbE_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A) that requires me to use R or Excel to find the answer to this:

Let $Y ∼ Gamma(2, 1/3)$. Find $P(0.5 < Y < 1.5)$. The answer is given as 0.078.

I would like to calculate this using Python. I have tried

```
from scipy import stats
stats.gamma.cdf(1.5,1/3,scale=2) - stats.gamma.cdf(0.5,1/3,scale=2)
```

which returns `0.197`. I've also tried switching the `2` and the `1/3`.

Note I am using

```
Python 3.5.3 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 15 2017, 10:43:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Beware the important distinction between the *gamma function* and the *gamma distribution*.. Your title appears to conflate the two. The gamma cdf is the regularized incomplete gamma function; the plain  "gamma function" appears as a normalizing constant in the gamma density.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks, I guess I want Gamma distribution. Any idea how to get the desired result in Python? The docs are pretty unclear as to what the parameters are

Comment: There are different ways to parameterize the gamma distribution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution. I'm sure the worksheet's usage does not match up with Python's default.

Comment: The question is using a different parameterization from the function you're calling. The following two posts should address all of your issues: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85974/how-do-you-estimate-the-predicted-probability-of-an-integer-value-from-a-negativ and 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80833/probability-interval-for-gamma-distribution

Comment: OK so after trying many combinations based on the wikipedia article Cliff posted, this is the parameterisation in Python that matches R: `stats.gamma.cdf(1.5,2,scale=3) - stats.gamma.cdf(0.5,2,scale=3)`